# jQuery hover with hidden content

Tags: jquery, hover, timeout, mouseover

I have the following code...

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var timer;

  $('.action-viewer').hide();
  $('.task').on('mouseover', function() {
    li = $(this);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      li.find('.action-viewer').show();
    }, 400);

  }).on('mouseout', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).find('.action-viewer').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.task-list {
  list-style: none
}
.task {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #EFEFEF
}
.action-viewer {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="task-list">
  <li class="task">This is task number 01
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 02
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 03
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 04
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 05
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

What is supposed to happen is when you hover over a task, the actions panel will show and the user can click the link. However as I move the mouse towards the link it disappears. This works without the timer, but I need the delay.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using shorthand `hover()` method for `mouseenter/mouseleave` and `delay()`:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var timer;

    $('.action-viewer').hide();

    $('.task').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.action-viewer').delay(400).show(0);
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.action-viewer').stop().hide();
    });

});
```

### -jsFiddle-

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`mouseleave` even](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/)t rather than the [`mouseout` event](https://api.jquery.com/mouseout/).

In doing so, the event isn't fired when leaving the element and hovering over the child.

Here is the updated example:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var timer;
  $('.action-viewer').hide();
  $('.task').on('mouseover', function() {
    var self = this;

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      $(self).find('.action-viewer').show();
    }, 400);
  }).on('mouseleave', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(this).find('.action-viewer').hide();
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 15px
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.task-list {
  list-style: none
}
.task {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top: 1px solid #EFEFEF
}
.action-viewer {
  border-top: 1px solid #CCC
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="task-list">
  <li class="task">This is task number 01
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 02
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 03
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 04
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="task">This is task number 05
    <div class="action-viewer"><a href="#">Action</a>
    </div>
  </li>
  <ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, this did what I wanted by ended up with some weird actions when I had multiple lists on one page.